# Error Having From using Inner Join Query while connecting 3 three tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I m trying to join three tables while using the join queries but when execute the code I have a face a syntax error in the FROM clause. I have write the snippet please suggest what is the error in my code.

```
 SELECT u.UserID, t.UserName,u.email, d.debit,d.credit,d.hand_on_cash
  FROM userdetails u JOIN usertable t  JOIN userdata d
  WHERE u.UserID=t.UserID
   AND u.UserID=d.UserID
  ORDER BY u.UserID,t.UserID
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the following link and edit the question appropriately by including the actual error you are getting:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing old style and new style join syntax.  You should use the latter:

```
SELECT
    u.UserID,
    t.UserName,
    u.email,
    d.debit,
    d.credit,
    d.hand_on_cash
FROM userdetails u
INNER JOIN usertable t
    ON u.UserID = t.UserID
INNER JOIN userdata d
    ON u.UserID = d.UserID
ORDER BY
    u.UserID,
    t.UserID
```

If you really wanted to use the old school Oracle style join, it would look like this:

```
SELECT
    u.UserID,
    t.UserName,
    u.email,
    d.debit,
    d.credit,
    d.hand_on_cash
FROM userdetails u, usertable t, userdata d   -- commas in the FROM clause
WHERE                                         -- not nice, but it should run
    u.UserID = t.UserID AND
    u.UserID = d.UserID                       -- the ON condition appears here
ORDER BY
    u.UserID,
    t.UserID
```

Comment: thanks bro, its **working successful**.I think this query would working on my project, I write the code like idiotic. anyway thanks for your suggestion.:-)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `ON` and don't need to use  `WHERE`

```
SELECT u.UserID, t.UserName,u.email, d.debit,d.credit,d.hand_on_cash
      FROM userdetails u JOIN usertable t ON u.UserID=t.UserID
      JOIN userdata d ON u.UserID=d.UserID
       --WHERE u.UserID=t.UserID
       --AND u.UserID=d.UserID
      ORDER BY u.UserID,t.UserID
```